Unable to wait for all tasks to complete in C++Builder
Here is my code:
PartsToTranslateCount = PartsToTranslate.size();
_di_ITask* ThreadList;
    
for (int i = 0; i < PartsToTranslateCount; i += nbMaxThreads->Value) {
    ThreadCount = System::Math::Min(int(nbMaxThreads->Value), int(PartsToTranslateCount - i));
    ThreadList  = new _di_ITask[ThreadCount];
    memoTranslatedText->Lines->Add("cicle #-" + IntToStr(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < ThreadCount; j++) {

        ThreadList[i + j] = TTask::Create([this, i, j]() {
            TThread::Synchronize(nullptr, _di_TThreadProcedure([this, i, j] {
                                     Application->ProcessMessages();
                                     this->memoTranslatedText->Lines->Add(IntToStr(i + j));
                                 }));
        });
        ThreadList[i + j]->Start();
    }
    TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList, (sizeof(ThreadList[0]) * ThreadCount) / sizeof(ThreadList[0]) - 1);
    //TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList, ThreadCount - 1);
    //TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList, sizeof(ThreadList)/sizeof(ThreadList[0])-1);
    delete[] ThreadList;
}
memoTranslatedText->Lines->Add("Done");

The program hangs unless the line TTask::WaitForAll() is not commented.
Help solve the problem.

ThreadList[i + j] should be ThreadList[j], you are going out of bounds. Consider using std::vector instead of new[]. But having a task that just calls TThread::Synchronize() is a waste of a task, why are you doing this? In any case, you MUST wait for the tasks to complete, so the call to TTask::WaitForAll() is required, but do use TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList, ThreadCount - 1); or the SLICE() macro in sysopen.h: TTask::WaitForAll(SLICE(ThreadList, ThreadCount));

@RemyLebeau
If you use a std::vector<_di_ITask> - how to correctly call the procedure TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList, ThreadCount - 1); ?
In this form, it is an error.
If you use a vector and an index j - there will be no overlap of thread?

You can use the vector's data() method: TTask::WaitForAll(ThreadList.data(), ThreadCount - 1) 
